# What is the type returned by createClient?

Tags: typescript, node-redis

I'm a TS noob but been writing some small services using TS. I'm working on a CLI tool build on top of [node-redis](https://github.com/redis/node-redis). Great redis client.

What is the type of `client` in the following snippet?

```
import { createClient } from "redis";

let client; // what is type of `client`?

client = createClient();
```

Inferring the type based on usage gives the following. Is there a way to clean this up? Thanks in advance.

```
import { createClient, RedisClientType, RedisScripts } from "redis";

let client: RedisClientType<{ json: { ARRAPPEND: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/ARRAPPEND"); arrAppend: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/ARRAPPEND"); ARRINDEX: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/ARRINDEX"); arrIndex: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/ARRINDEX"); ARRINSERT: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/ARRINSERT"); arrInsert: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/ARRINSERT"); ARRLEN: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/ARRLEN"); arrLen: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/ARRLEN"); ARRPOP: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/ARRPOP"); arrPop: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/ARRPOP"); ARRTRIM: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/ARRTRIM"); arrTrim: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/ARRTRIM"); DEBUG_MEMORY: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/DEBUG_MEMORY"); debugMemory: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/DEBUG_MEMORY"); DEL: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/DEL"); del: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/DEL"); FORGET: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/FORGET"); forget: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/FORGET"); GET: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/GET"); get: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/GET"); MGET: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/MGET"); mGet: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/MGET"); NUMINCRBY: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/NUMINCRBY"); numIncrBy: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/NUMINCRBY"); NUMMULTBY: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/NUMMULTBY"); numMultBy: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/NUMMULTBY"); OBJKEYS: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/OBJKEYS"); objKeys: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/OBJKEYS"); OBJLEN: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/OBJLEN"); objLen: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/OBJLEN"); RESP: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/RESP"); resp: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/RESP"); SET: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/SET"); set: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/SET"); STRAPPEND: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/STRAPPEND"); strAppend: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/STRAPPEND"); STRLEN: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/STRLEN"); strLen: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/STRLEN"); TYPE: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/TYPE"); type: typeof import("@node-redis/json/dist/commands/TYPE"); }; ft: { _LIST: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/_LIST"); _list: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/_LIST"); ALTER: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/ALTER"); alter: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/ALTER"); AGGREGATE: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/AGGREGATE"); aggregate: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/AGGREGATE"); ALIASADD: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/ALIASADD"); aliasAdd: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/ALIASADD"); ALIASDEL: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/ALIASDEL"); aliasDel: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/ALIASDEL"); ALIASUPDATE: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/ALIASUPDATE"); aliasUpdate: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/ALIASUPDATE"); CONFIG_GET: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/CONFIG_GET"); configGet: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/CONFIG_GET"); CONFIG_SET: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/CONFIG_SET"); configSet: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/CONFIG_SET"); CREATE: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/CREATE"); create: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/CREATE"); DICTADD: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/DICTADD"); dictAdd: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/DICTADD"); DICTDEL: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/DICTDEL"); dictDel: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/DICTDEL"); DICTDUMP: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/DICTDUMP"); dictDump: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/DICTDUMP"); DROPINDEX: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/DROPINDEX"); dropIndex: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/DROPINDEX"); EXPLAIN: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/EXPLAIN"); explain: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/EXPLAIN"); EXPLAINCLI: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/EXPLAINCLI"); explainCli: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/EXPLAINCLI"); INFO: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/INFO"); info: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/INFO"); PROFILESEARCH: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/PROFILE_SEARCH"); profileSearch: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/PROFILE_SEARCH"); PROFILEAGGREGATE: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/PROFILE_AGGREGATE"); profileAggregate: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/PROFILE_AGGREGATE"); SEARCH: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/SEARCH"); search: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/SEARCH"); SPELLCHECK: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/SPELLCHECK"); spellCheck: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/SPELLCHECK"); SUGADD: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/SUGADD"); sugAdd: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/SUGADD"); SUGDEL: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/SUGDEL"); sugDel: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/SUGDEL"); SUGGET_WITHPAYLOADS: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/SUGGET_WITHPAYLOADS"); sugGetWithPayloads: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/SUGGET_WITHPAYLOADS"); SUGGET_WITHSCORES_WITHPAYLOADS: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/SUGGET_WITHSCORES_WITHPAYLOADS"); sugGetWithScoresWithPayloads: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/SUGGET_WITHSCORES_WITHPAYLOADS"); SUGGET_WITHSCORES: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/SUGGET_WITHSCORES"); sugGetWithScores: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/SUGGET_WITHSCORES"); SUGGET: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/SUGGET"); sugGet: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/SUGGET"); SUGLEN: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/SUGLEN"); sugLen: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/SUGLEN"); SYNDUMP: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/SYNDUMP"); synDump: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/SYNDUMP"); SYNUPDATE: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/SYNUPDATE"); synUpdate: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/SYNUPDATE"); TAGVALS: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/TAGVALS"); tagVals: typeof import("@node-redis/search/dist/commands/TAGVALS"); }; ts: { ADD: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/ADD"); add: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/ADD"); ALTER: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/ALTER"); alter: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/ALTER"); CREATE: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/CREATE"); create: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/CREATE"); CREATERULE: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/CREATERULE"); createRule: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/CREATERULE"); DECRBY: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/DECRBY"); decrBy: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/DECRBY"); DEL: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/DEL"); del: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/DEL"); DELETERULE: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/DELETERULE"); deleteRule: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/DELETERULE"); GET: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/GET"); get: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/GET"); INCRBY: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/INCRBY"); incrBy: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/INCRBY"); INFO_DEBUG: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/INFO_DEBUG"); infoDebug: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/INFO_DEBUG"); INFO: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/INFO"); info: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/INFO"); MADD: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/MADD"); mAdd: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/MADD"); MGET: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/MGET"); mGet: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/MGET"); MGET_WITHLABELS: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/MGET_WITHLABELS"); mGetWithLabels: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/MGET_WITHLABELS"); QUERYINDEX: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/QUERYINDEX"); queryIndex: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/QUERYINDEX"); RANGE: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/RANGE"); range: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/RANGE"); REVRANGE: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/REVRANGE"); revRange: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/REVRANGE"); MRANGE: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/MRANGE"); mRange: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/MRANGE"); MRANGE_WITHLABELS: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/MRANGE_WITHLABELS"); mRangeWithLabels: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/MRANGE_WITHLABELS"); MREVRANGE: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/MREVRANGE"); mRevRange: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/MREVRANGE"); MREVRANGE_WITHLABELS: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/MREVRANGE_WITHLABELS"); mRevRangeWithLabels: typeof import("@node-redis/time-series/dist/commands/MREVRANGE_WITHLABELS"); }; bf: { ADD: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/bloom/ADD"); add: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/bloom/ADD"); EXISTS: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/bloom/EXISTS"); exists: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/bloom/EXISTS"); INFO: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/bloom/INFO"); info: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/bloom/INFO"); INSERT: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/bloom/INSERT"); insert: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/bloom/INSERT"); LOADCHUNK: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/bloom/LOADCHUNK"); loadChunk: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/bloom/LOADCHUNK"); MADD: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/bloom/MADD"); mAdd: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/bloom/MADD"); MEXISTS: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/bloom/MEXISTS"); mExists: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/bloom/MEXISTS"); RESERVE: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/bloom/RESERVE"); reserve: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/bloom/RESERVE"); SCANDUMP: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/bloom/SCANDUMP"); scanDump: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/bloom/SCANDUMP"); }; cms: { INCRBY: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/count-min-sketch/INCRBY"); incrBy: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/count-min-sketch/INCRBY"); INFO: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/count-min-sketch/INFO"); info: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/count-min-sketch/INFO"); INITBYDIM: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/count-min-sketch/INITBYDIM"); initByDim: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/count-min-sketch/INITBYDIM"); INITBYPROB: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/count-min-sketch/INITBYPROB"); initByProb: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/count-min-sketch/INITBYPROB"); MERGE: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/count-min-sketch/MERGE"); merge: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/count-min-sketch/MERGE"); QUERY: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/count-min-sketch/QUERY"); query: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/count-min-sketch/QUERY"); }; cf: { ADD: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/cuckoo/ADD"); add: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/cuckoo/ADD"); ADDNX: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/cuckoo/ADDNX"); addNX: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/cuckoo/ADDNX"); COUNT: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/cuckoo/COUNT"); count: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/cuckoo/COUNT"); DEL: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/cuckoo/DEL"); del: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/cuckoo/DEL"); EXISTS: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/cuckoo/EXISTS"); exists: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/cuckoo/EXISTS"); INFO: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/cuckoo/INFO"); info: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/cuckoo/INFO"); INSERT: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/cuckoo/INSERT"); insert: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/cuckoo/INSERT"); INSERTNX: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/cuckoo/INSERTNX"); insertNX: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/cuckoo/INSERTNX"); LOADCHUNK: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/cuckoo/LOADCHUNK"); loadChunk: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/cuckoo/LOADCHUNK"); RESERVE: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/cuckoo/RESERVE"); reserve: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/cuckoo/RESERVE"); SCANDUMP: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/cuckoo/SCANDUMP"); scanDump: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/cuckoo/SCANDUMP"); }; topK: { ADD: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/top-k/ADD"); add: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/top-k/ADD"); COUNT: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/top-k/COUNT"); count: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/top-k/COUNT"); INCRBY: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/top-k/INCRBY"); incrBy: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/top-k/INCRBY"); INFO: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/top-k/INFO"); info: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/top-k/INFO"); LIST: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/top-k/LIST"); list: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/top-k/LIST"); QUERY: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/top-k/QUERY"); query: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/top-k/QUERY"); RESERVE: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/top-k/RESERVE"); reserve: typeof import("@node-redis/bloom/dist/commands/top-k/RESERVE"); }; }, RedisScripts>; 

client = createClient();
```

Comment: Simple `client: RedisClientType` works at least nowadays just fine.

Comment: @leppaott, you're right. I believe that was not present in the earlier versions of the library.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the type utility [`ReturnType<FunctionType>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) to derive the type you need, like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQYQDbBoB28AvnAGZQQhwBE6AJsAM50DcAUJ3mvMgWIwAXHABKfAK5QiAFQCeYNAB4YitBAop0WXIJIA+LgMIk4AXm2Zs+UzAAUASi5A)

```ts
import { createClient } from "redis";

let client: ReturnType<typeof createClient>;
```

---

For [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) functions see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76058793/438273), and for generic methods see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75884317/438273).

Comment: This is great. Thanks for this tip :D