# Can one supply a type to a property that has a generic

Tags: typescript

How can one provide the generic to a property, such that one can get its type after applying that generic:

```js
type Foo = { foo<T>(arg: T): T }

// y's type below is (arg: string) => string
const y = ('whatever' as unknown as Foo).foo<string>  

// is there any way to replicate that using only types?
type Bar = Foo['foo']<string> // should return (arg: string) => string
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=34&pln=7&pc=40#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKAzBAeAKgPgAoBDAJwHMAuKXASmtygF8AoFgenahAHIBnKKQjAArqQB2UUJCgAjCABs4AdygBLASQrU+wUmvHlayfFF37DLAMZxxu7siiEeygBbFgEAG4RSPKMQCIuIA1uIqkoGwCLQAdFhw2OYG5KZQbJzqAsCuvtDE4iDKxCBSiEJgCmpWHtA5HlAifClQtgql0hB8APwsnVAAQmSO8HAA2jwJPAC6SXopppl8rnAiCgAmgsJiklpUZvOGxkimyYZAA)

Comment: TypeScript doesn't have [Higher-Kinded Types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), but you can declare an unused value to derive the applied generic function type like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3BaLN) and it'll still be erased in the emit. Does that address your question? If so, I can write it up as an answer — if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jsejcksn - just discovered why that will not solve my problem: one can't use declare inside of a function ...

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75883973/can-one-supply-a-type-to-a-property-that-has-a-generic/75884317#comment133850161_75883973) @TrevTheDev If there are additional constraints, please edit the question so that it reflects the actual problem — with a [mre].

Comment: @jsejcksn thanks for answering this.  I found the final solution.  in addition to using `declare` I can simply declare a dummy function within my function and then access its return type as per your solution.  Admittedly this will create some junk in the JS, but at least the Typing will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until TypeScript gets [Higher-Kinded Types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), you can create a [value declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#global-variables) which represents `Foo`, and then derive the function type with the applied generic using an [instantiation expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions).

Keep in mind that if you use this technique, it might be helpful to name the declared value something that reminds you not to use it in a runtime expression (because it doesn't actually exist).

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKAzBAeAKgPgAoBDAJwHMAuKXASmtygF8BuAKDYBMIBjAGzLQecAHYBnYFAD6U3AAkAkgGUpAdQDyAOVxSAogA1lOgII6ASgFVtCgLK6p8ONUfs2oSFABCZZFHcQ4DGlZRRUNbT1DJRNzK1xbe0cAOiw4bAlSAEsRcnxXfy8yAAUyYgBbMV8S0nKIYAhSMWxvUjy2KA6Aek6APQB+DgKWszqAV1IRXHBoFBHgccnp5rI2jqhu-rYgA)

```ts
type Foo = { foo<T>(arg: T): T };

declare const __THIS_WONT_EXIST_AT_RUNTIME_Foo: Foo;

type Bar = typeof __THIS_WONT_EXIST_AT_RUNTIME_Foo.foo<string>;

type BarParams = Parameters<Bar>;
   //^? type BarParams = [arg: string]

type BarReturnType = ReturnType<Bar>;
   //^? type BarReturnType = string
```