# Use typeof on inline function call

Tags: typescript

I'm just wondering if there is any way to call typeof directly on a function call, in the context of typescript, for example assigning to a type.

For example, suppose we have simple identity function

```
const identity =<T extends unknown>(x:T)=>x;
```

Then can get the type for 5 by first calling identity with 5 and then typeof on the result.

```
const five = identity(5);

type Five = typeof five
```

But say we want to directly get the type for "s"

```
type S = typeof identity("s") //cant do this. ';' expected.(1005)
type S2 = typeof (identity("s")) //cant do this. Exported type alias 'S2' has or is using private name ''.
```

Wonder if there is a way, not that it matters much, but some cases could be useful.

Also if not possible would be cool to know why, is typescript expecting some particular symbol after typeof?

Thanks

Comment: You want the ReturnType utility type

Comment: ReturnType will give unknown for identity. Found the answer though https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html#limitations. I guess its intentional and wants identifier.

Comment: You can specify the parameter type, identity is a generic function. `ReturnType<identity<string>>`

Comment: Yea nice, you can specify for the function without calling it. Works nicely for example like this where you have the same type exactly for the generic and argument. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of the utility [`ReturnType<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) and [instantiation expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) (applied generic), like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlgEwKZinKBPGBeGAeAFRiQA8oUEIYBXMAazBAHcwA+AChIC4YCBKHKxgkA3ACgxmAA5IYAZRwwASkijUATmAIYZeaUhAAzeMlToMeAEQRLrVuJiOA9E4B6AfjFA)

```ts
const identity = <T extends unknown>(x: T) => x;

type S = ReturnType<typeof identity<"s">>;
   //^? type S = "s"
```